# Get Value of Foreign Key in Django-rest Serializer

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am trying to get value of foreign key , but i am only getting id, my code below

```
Model:
    class DocumentType(models.Model):
    """Model for type of documents type system is indexing"""
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False)

def __str__(self):
    return "{}".format(self.title)


class DocumentsCount(models.Model):
    """Model for type of documents count system is indexing"""
    document_type = models.ForeignKey(DocumentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='doc_title')
    count = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return "{}".format(self.document_type)
```

Serializer

```
class DocumentCountsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
title = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source="DocumentType.title")

class Meta:
    model = DocumentsCount
    fields = "__all__"
```

Out put I am getting from API

```
    {
    "id": 5,
    "count": 2,
    "document_type": 3
}
```

document_type should be title , but i am getting ID

this is query

```
 queryset = DocumentsCount.objects.select_related('document_type')
```

I am not sure what did I did wrong, I am in fact getting ID and Title when u print `queryset` and run in sqlite

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a mistake in specifying the source. Change it to `source="document_type.title"` because you want to say "use the `title` of the `document_type` field of this instance":

```
class DocumentCountsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    title = serializers.CharField(source="document_type.title", read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = DocumentsCount
        fields = "__all__"
```

You were having a problem because there's no field `DocumentType` defined on the `DocumentsCount` model (the field is `document_type` which is a foreign key to `DocumentType`).

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use ***StringRelatedField*** property/attribute of rest framework while making serializers. It gives output as per the definition in ***__str__(self)*** of the model.

See an example (if one to Many: you can use many=True):

Your snippet will go like this:

```
class DocumentCountsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    document_type = serializers.StringRelatedField()

    class Meta:
        model = DocumentsCount
        fields = "__all__"
```

To add on (an additional info), if the serializer was of your `class DocumentType` , then we have to use: many=True, example is in subsequent field:

```
class DocumentTypeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # here we use related_name 'doc_title' for the relationship
    doc_title = serializers.StringRelatedField(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = DocumentsType
        fields = "__all__"
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your model to support nested serializer like this

```
class DocumentTypeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
       class Meta:
            model = DocumentType
            fields = "__all__"
class DocumentCountsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    doc_title = DocumentTypeSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = DocumentsCount
        fields = "__all__"
```

By calling the DocumentCountsSerializer for fetching data automatically fetch related foreign key values.

Call the serializer as follows:

```
queryset = DocumentsCount.objects.all()
serializer = serializers.DocumentTypeSerializer(queryset, many=True)
```

Comment: getting name error `    doc_title = DocumentTypeSerializer(many=True)
NameError: name 'DocumentTypeSerializer' is not defined
`

Comment: Now try. I edited the code. Write DocumentTypeSerializer above DocumentCountsSerializer

Answer (score 0):

The answer posted by a_k_v is correct and will return a nested serializer within the `DocumentCountsSerializer()`.

Alternatively if you want a response like this with:

`{
    "id": 5,
    "count": 2,
    "title": "title here"
}`

You need to update your serializer accordingly. Considering the query your run with select_related, your serializers will look something like this:

```
class DocumentCountsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    title = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = DocumentsCount
        fields = "__all__"

     def get_title(self, obj):
         return obj.document_type.title
```